# how to display a statement in text widget of tkinter after getting input thru get statement

Tags: python, tkinter, text, get, tkinter-entry

```
from tkinter import *

def tell_story(Male):
    story= "My name is" + "Male"
    Frame.story_txt.delete(0.0, END)
    Frame.story_txt.insert(0.0, story)
    root = Tk()
    root.title("game")
    root.geometry("800x400")
    Application = Frame(root)
    Application.grid()
    Lbl1 = Label(Application, text="story").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
    Lbl2 = Label(Application, text="Male name").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
    Male = Entry(Application).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)   
    Button(Application, text="Click for story", command=tell_story).grid(row=11, column=0, sticky=W)
    Frame.story_txt = Text(Application, width=75, height=10, wrap=WORD)
    Frame.story_txt.grid(row=12, column=0, columnspan=4)
    root.mainloop()
```

I'm unable to print story variable in text widget

Comment: You need to format your code correctly and provide clearer details as to what you're doing and what's happening.

Comment: Hi, I've formatted your code. Please review it and make sure it's what you have. [Edit] as needed. That said, you should always format your questions properly. Also include expected and actual behavior, "unable to ..." is too unspecific. See [ask].

Comment: Thanks for formatting the code. I was trying to create a madlib game and above code is part of it. Trying to display the text "My name is " in the text widget of the tkinter window. Intention is to get the variable 'Male' entry from user and add to variable 'story' and print as say 'My name is avin' where Male = avin. unable to get input thru function tell story with button widget